# How to change table's border color in AsciiDoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

After Googling on and on, I couldn't find a way to change table's border color. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the artifact you are exporting to.

If you are exporting to html, you have to change the css style that is applied to the table. Either by changing the asciidoctor.css or by appling a different stylesheet with the :stylesheet: attribute (remember to overwrite with !important otherwise it will not be applied). You can modify the `th` and `td` tags of the table with `border-color: 1px solid red`, for example.

If you are exporting to pdf, you have to use a ...-theme.yml file which you have to specify with the :pdf-style: attribute. table_border_color is the key you are looking for (see also the [asciidoctor theming guide](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc#keys-table)).